# how to see multiple column values in new line

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to query multiple row data in single column in oracle?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16238/how-to-query-multiple-row-data-in-single-column-in-oracle)

my table structure is given bellow

```
deptid  ename
------  ------
10  CLARK,KING,MILLER
20  ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
```

but i want the output sould be 
like

```
deptid  ename
----------------
10      CLARK,
        KING,
        MILLER
------------------
20      ADAMS,
        FORD,
        JONES,
        SCOTT,
        SMITH
```

please tell me how to do it in sql

Comment: Why is that your table structure? Having comma delimited multiple values in a single column violates first normal form. Also your desired results appear to be something that should be done in the presentation layer anyway.

Comment: this is not the tabele structurewhat  you are showing us. it is (perhaps) the output of a select statement. you also did not show the query you execute to get the output. @Martin Smith wrote that it depends on the tool you use to display the output of the query. i suppose you use sqlplus to produce this output but you should tell us what tool you use.

Comment: Thanks for your answar.this clears my doubt regards sabyasachi

Answer (score 0):

> select deptid, replace(ename, ',', ',\n') from table;

Try to use this query and it will gives you your expected result.