# how to query multiple row data in single column in oracle?

Tags: oracle

i have a table in which the values are

```
id      value
----------------
1         10
1         20
1         30
2         33
2         34
```

I want the output given below using sql:

```
id          value
-------------------
1             10
              20
              30
--------------------
2             33
              34
--------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Query:

```
SELECT id, ListAgg(to_char(value), chr(10) || chr(13)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) "Values" 
FROM t1 GROUP BY id;
```

Output:

```
ID Values   
-- ----------
 1 10         
   20          
   30          

 2 33         
   34
```

Setup:

```
DROP TABLE T1;
CREATE TABLE t1 AS (SELECT 1 id, level * 10 value FROM dual CONNECT BY level <=3);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2,33);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2,34);
```

Comment: Note that `listagg` requires Oracle 11g.